# QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate class

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am using hql to generate an actual Java object of class JunctionManagementListDto. But I end up with the following exception on my console

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate class [JunctionManagementListDto] [SELECT new JunctionManagementListDto(c.siteId, c.name, c.ip, c.customer.id, zm.zone.name) FROM com.traff.hibernate.model.Controllers c, com.traff.hibernate.model.ZoneControllerMapping zm WHERE c.siteId = zm.controller.siteId  ]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:79)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:255)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:221)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:199)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1735)
at com.traff.hibernate.generic.GenericDAOImpl.readListByHql(GenericDAOImpl.java:107)
at com.traff.hibernate.daoImpl.JnMgmtLogDaoImpl.getJunctionManagementList(JnMgmtLogDaoImpl.java:29)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy175.getJunctionManagementList(Unknown Source)
at com.traff.service.report.JunctionManagementReportService.prepareStatusList(JunctionManagementReportService.java:37)
at com.traff.service.report.JunctionManagementReportService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$472093e1.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
......
```

My hql query is written inside JnMgmtLogDaoImpl class with all necessary imports as

```
public List<JunctionManagementListDto> getJunctionManagementList(String zoneName, Integer customerId) {     
    String hql =    "SELECT new JunctionManagementListDto(c.siteId, c.name, c.ip, c.customer.id, zm.zone.name) "
            +"FROM Controllers c, ZoneControllerMapping zm "
            +"WHERE c.siteId = zm.controller.siteId  ";

    if(zoneName != "")
        hql += "  and zm.zone.name='"+zoneName+"' ";
     if (customerId!=null)
        hql += "  and zm.controller.customer.id='"+customerId+"' ";
    return super.readListByHql(hql);        
}
```

and JunctionManagementListDto is declared as

public class JunctionManagementListDto {

```
private String zoneName;
private Integer siteId;
private String name;
private String ip;
private Integer customerId;
public String getZoneName() {
    return zoneName;
}
public void setZoneName(String zoneName) {
    this.zoneName = zoneName;
}
public Integer getSiteId() {
    return siteId;
}
public void setSiteId(Integer siteId) {
    this.siteId = siteId;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getIp() {
    return ip;
}
public void setIp(String ip) {
    this.ip = ip;
}
public Integer getCustomerName() {
    return customerId;
}
public void setCustomerName(Integer customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
}

public JunctionManagementListDto(Integer siteId, String zoneName, String ip, Integer customerId, String junctionName) {
    super();
    this.siteId = siteId;
    this.customerId = customerId;
    this.ip = ip;
    this.zoneName = zoneName;
    name = junctionName;
}

public JunctionManagementListDto(){

}
}
```

What is causing this exception and how can I solve it?

Comment: Is the JAR file (or whatever) containing the on the >>runtime<< classpath?

Comment: @StephenC yes no problems in that part.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I resolved this issue by specifying the fully qualified name of the constructor.

```
public List<JunctionManagementListDto> getJunctionManagementList(String zoneName, Integer customerId) {     
String hql =    "SELECT new (packagename).JunctionManagementListDto(c.siteId, c.name, c.ip, c.customer.id, zm.zone.name) "
        +"FROM Controllers c, ZoneControllerMapping zm "
        +"WHERE c.siteId = zm.controller.siteId  ";

if(zoneName != "")
    hql += "  and zm.zone.name='"+zoneName+"' ";
 if (customerId!=null)
    hql += "  and zm.controller.customer.id='"+customerId+"' ";
return super.readListByHql(hql);        
}
```

Comment: Thanks. this helped me.

Comment: You can use `Clazz.class.getName()` to get the full name:
`"SELECT new "+JunctionManagementListDto.class.getName()+"(c.siteId, c.name, [...]"`.

Answer (score 3):

This error also occurs when attempting to construct an inner class. The class must be declared in its own file.

e.g.

```
package a.b.c;

public class Foo {

  public static final class Bar {
      public final int x;
      public Bar(int x) { this.x = x; }
  }

  public void baz() {
      // some HQL involving `new a.b.c.Foo.Bar(x)`
  }
}
```

will result in `QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate class` at runtime. `Bar` must be defined as a standalone class before HQL can resolve it.