# Spring data JPA: getting No aliases found in result tuple! error when executing custom query

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to execute a custom query on the mysql database using the `@Query` annotation of spring data jpa.

The table is

```
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id         | decimal(10,0) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| first_name | varchar(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| last_name  | varchar(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

and the query as in mysql is

```
select last_name,count(last_name) as count from person group by last_name;
```

---

While implementing this in Spring data jpa. I'm using this logic,

1. create another class `CountPerson` that holds two variables, `last_name` and `count`
2. Use @Query to write the query, and the method returns list of object of `CountPerson` class.

The query as in spring data jpa is

```
@Query("select p.lastName,count(p.lastName) as count from Person p group by p.lastName")
```

---

While the code compiles and the web server starts fine, when I try to run the related method, I get

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
No aliases found in result tuple! Make sure your query defines aliases!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No aliases found in result tuple! Make sure your query defines aliases!
```

Searching for this error shows [spring data jpa: No aliases found in result tuple! Make sure your query defines aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37658619/spring-data-jpa-no-aliases-found-in-result-tuple-make-sure-your-query-defines) which says that it is a fixed bug. So I guess my issue is different

---

The codes are

Person class

```
//imports

@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person{

    @Id
    Long id;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    private Person(){}
    //constructor
}
```

Person repository class

```
//imports
@Transactional
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person,Long>{

    @Query("select p.lastName,count(p.lastName) as count from Person p group by p.lastName")
    public List<CountPerson> countbylastname();
}
```

Controller class

```
@Controller
public class PersonController{

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping("/count")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<CountPerson> countbylastname(){
        return repository.countbylastname();
    }
}
```

Count Person class

```
public class CountPerson{
    String lastName;
    int count;

    protected CountPerson(){}

    public CountPerson(String lastName,int count){
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

Comment: What versino of spring data are you using ?

Comment: @reos I haven't mentioned a specific version in gradle build file.

Comment: See what version are you getting.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Almost there... (by heart, so I hope it's perfect) You'll need to create a new CountPerson(...)

```
select new com.mypackage.CountPerson(p.last_name, count(p.last_name)) from person p ...
```

The JpaRepository can only easily return Person objects, but you can create objects in HQL yourself.

Comment: Worked!!! Had some more bugs but got it working. Thanks! I owe you a whole semester.

Comment: As reference to future readers, you must use fully qualified name as in com.example.classname http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39122437/querysyntaxexception-unable-to-locate-class

Comment: I can't believe that was the answer to my solution... you can do "new SomeClass" inside an @Query... ? no way...

Answer (score 7):

A more clean solution is to use [Spring Data JPA Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections):

Yo must replace class for a interface and define only get methods:

```
public interface CountPerson {

    String getLastName();

    int getCount();
}
```

Your Repository method seem like this:

```
@Query("select p.lastName as lastName,count(p.lastName) as count from Person p group by p.lastName")
public List<CountPerson> countbylastname();
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47420600/spring-data-projection-and-error-no-aliases-found-in-result-tuple-make-sure-y

Comment: I know this is old, but I had this error: `A TupleBackedMap cannot be modified`