# Spring Data Projection and Error: "No aliases found in result tuple! Make sure your query defines aliases!"

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

The below approach to get a Spring Data Projection from a JPA Query doesn't work for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45443776/1005607

My table:

**LOOKUP_T**

```
id   description    display_order_num
------------------------------------
1    Category #1    1
2    Category #2    2
```

**ACTIVITIES_T (activity_category_id maps to LOOKUP_T.id)**

```
id  activity_category_id  activity_title
---------------------------------------
1      2                  Sleeping
2      2                  Eating
3      2                  Travel
```

Spring Data DAO Interface to get certain fields from this join:

```
@Repository
public interface ActivitiesDAO extends JpaRepository<ActivitiesT, Integer> {

    @Query("select a.activityTitle, l.description as category, " + 
           "l.displayOrderNum as categoryDisplayOrderNum " + 
           "from ActivitiesT a, LookupT l " + 
           "where a.lookupT.id = l.id order by l.displayOrderNum asc ")
    public List<MySpringDataProjection> findCustom();

}
```

Spring Data Projection Model Interface:

```
public interface MySpringDataProjection {

    public String getActivityTitle();

    public String getCategory();

    public Integer getCategoryDisplayOrderNum();

}
```

Everything is the same as in that accepted answer. But getting this error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No aliases found in result tuple! Make sure your query defines aliases!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No aliases found in result tuple! Make sure your query defines aliases!
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:381)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:489)
    org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
```

I don't want to use `select new Obj(..)` in the Query, it's dirty and relies on Hibernate which we're abstracting out to JPA.

I want to get this Projection approach to work.

Related question which had the (non-working) answer I referenced,
[Spring data JPA: getting No aliases found in result tuple! error when executing custom query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42419305/spring-data-jpa-getting-no-aliases-found-in-result-tuple-error-when-executing)

Comment: What are you trying to do with the projection? A simpler approach might be just to get the ActivityT object instead and get the lookup information from that.

Comment: I need particular fields from a join. If I were using a domain object (ActivityT) I would need an Eager Fetch to get associations, right? But maybe I don't want to always eagerly fetch the LookupID, but I want lazy fetches most of the time. This would have allowed me to get exactly what I want without any headaches in going the Lazy/Eager route.

Comment: You could do a couple things. Create one method that does an eager fetch via join fetch and another method that just does a normal join or you could fetch your ActivityT object and then use that object in another query to query the LookupT table.  I haven't messed with Spring projections personally so I don't know how to really answer your original question but can suggest the work arounds to get you through the problem. The methods above is typically what I've done to get information

Comment: Yeah the problem is that all these horrible technologies like Spring Data and JPA and ORM were meant to "simplify" and "improve" the development process and it turns out all we're doing 90% of the time is working around them. Just a comment.

Comment: Asking people what JPQL should be requires you to provide the entity classes, and you haven't. And if you find yourself "working around" software then you are likely using it for something it wasn't intended for. But then you can rant away all you want :-P

Answer (score 8):

I encounter the same problem. After try several changes, I found we just need to add "as" for each column(even the column name is not changed) in NativeQuery. For you here, change your sql like :

```
    @Query("select a.activityTitle **as activityTitle**, l.description as category, " + 
       "l.displayOrderNum as categoryDisplayOrderNum " + 
       "from ActivitiesT a, LookupT l " + 
       "where a.lookupT.id = l.id order by l.displayOrderNum asc ")
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and i think i solve it. What i did is to use alias in all field, even if they have the same name. Use alias in activityTitle too. Like this:

```
@Repository
public interface ActivitiesDAO extends JpaRepository<ActivitiesT, Integer> {

    @Query("select a.activityTitle as activityTitle, l.description as category, " + 
           "l.displayOrderNum as categoryDisplayOrderNum " + 
           "from ActivitiesT a, LookupT l " + 
           "where a.lookupT.id = l.id order by l.displayOrderNum asc ")
    public List<MySpringDataProjection> findCustom();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you must define exact name methods in the interface, but i'm not sure this approach apply to your case.

> The important bit here is that the properties defined here exactly match properties in the aggregate root. This allows a query method to be added like this

In your example, you could try an [Open Projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces.open)